# Write a program that gets an integer , which its number of digits is not specified. then print each digit n times if n is the digit itself

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, for-loop, while-loop

How can I solve this problem?
like this:
6041
6: 666666
0:
4: 4444
1: 1
I just know that for separating numbers we should do this, I think:

```
num = int(input)
while num > 0:
res = num // 10
num = num % 10
```

Comment: Cool, but what is your question ?

Comment: ah sorry, how can I write this program?
Can you please help me?

Comment: Well, your first snippet is not bad (adjust indentation). Now only remains to output the digits (res) with replication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to keep the number as a string, then in a loop convert the first digit to an int, print it n times, then remove it. Repeat the loop until the string is empty:

```
num = input("Input a number: ")
while len(num) > 0:
    digit = num[0]
    for i in range(int(digit)):
        print(digit, end="")
    num = num[1:]
```

Comment: Thanks !!!! ^_^

Comment: @Mee Please accept my answer if it solved your problem

Comment: Yes, Of course :)